# conversion from textbox string to decimal

Tags: c#

I am facing a problem while conversting string to decimal.

```
decimal num = convert.todecimal(textbox1.text);
```

for example: if the value is 2.50 in textbox then I get num = 250 after conversion. The "." is removed from the string. I wanna get the value as it is written in text box.

Please give any solution

Comment: And what if your users type "ABCD" in your textbox?

Comment: I suggest `Decimal.TryParse`.

Comment: only one "." and numbers are allowed.

Comment: I tried convert.todouble() and decimal.tryparse() both of them. but did not work

Comment: Are the culture settings expecting a comma instead of a decimal?  Is there other code which is modifying the input string before you parse it?  Show your exact attempt with `TryParse()` and what the inputs and outputs were.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is your `CurrentCulture` by the way?  Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: "Did not work" isn't very helpful. What were the errors you got?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fiddle for Decimal.TryParse:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/lDbfei

```
using System;
using System.Net;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string myval = "put a number / your value here";
        decimal d = 0;
        var result = decimal.TryParse(myval, out d);
        Console.WriteLine(result);  
        Console.WriteLine(d);
    }
}
```

Comment: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: I have added the code in too. I would say that JSFiddle, .NetFiddle, Plnkr are all acceptable ways of presenting answers, but yes, the Fiddle may have a different lifespan to the stackoverflow post.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
decimal temp;
decimal.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out temp);
```

Another Example from this:

```
 if(decimal.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out temp))
        {
            if(textBox1.Text.Contains(","))
            {
               textBox1.Text =  textBox1.Text.Replace(',', '.');
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

There´s the static method `Decimal.TryParse` which you may use for this:

```
decimal myDec;
if (!Decimal.TryParse(mytextboxesContent, out myDec)) {
    // do whatever you want to if the content is not valid;
}
```

The return-value of this method also gives you the opportunity to react on invalid input (such as "abc" or "1,3,4").

Answer (score 0):

When you try to convert input from users, you should not blindly accept everything that is passed to you otherwise you face the risk to incur in many exceptions.

This is the design decision behind the many version of the `TryParse` family of methods. 
Check if your input could be converted in the correct data type and advise with a return value if this is not possible, do not throw exceptions. If the conversion is possible initialize the passed out variable with the result of the conversion

Then, there is the problem of localizations. In some cultures the comma signals the start of the decimal part of a number while other cultures likes the point symbol. 
This could be resolved trying the conversion with the `CurrentCulture` and in case of failure trying  the `InvariantCulture`

```
string dec = "2.5"; // Not good for cultures that likes a comma as decimal symbol
decimal d;
if(!decimal.TryParse(dec, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out d))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Not a valid number in current culture");
    if(!decimal.TryParse(dec, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out d))
        MessageBox.Show("Type a valid number please!");
}

MessageBox.Show("Valid number:" + d.ToString());
```

Of course, if you are certain that there is no possibility to enter an invalid symbol for the decimal separator, then you could use only one if with the CultureInfo.InvariantCulture localization. (But pay attention to some simple user actions like Copy/Paste from the Calculator to your textboxes).